# Inline C# code should be run only when clicked ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, anchor, ascx

```
  <a href='MainPage.aspx<%=Session["IDs"] = null%>'>Log out</a>
```

The above code is written in Navigation.ascx(Web Form User Control), and navigation is registered in almost all website pages. Now i want above code <%=Session["IDs"] = null%> to run only when i click on log-out.

> Rite Now when i navigate to any page the above code runs every time. I am navigating through anchor tag.
>
> **NEW CODE
>
> `<a runat="server" id="alogout" onclick="logout_click" href="#">Log out</a>`
>
> protected void logout_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>           {
>               Session["IDs"] = null;
>               Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
>           }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Add ID for the :

   ```
   <'a runat="server" id="my_anchor" href='MainPage.aspx' onclick="anchor_click">Log out</a>
   ```

   then add a method on the code behind:

   ```
   protected void anchor_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Session["IDs"] = null;
   }
   ```
2. Change the href to another page that has Session["IDs"] = null and redirect to MainPage.aspx:
   `<a href='RedirectToMainPage.aspx'>Log out</a>`

Comment: add id means adding id="..." to the element, and why read only? show me your new code

Comment: <a runat="server" id="alogout" onclick="logout_click" href="#">Log out</a>

protected void logout_click(object sender, EventArgs e) { Session["IDs"] = null; Response.Redirect("Login.aspx"); }

Comment: i have put # in href. Now i can click but code wont work

Comment: Leave it. i have used option# 2. Ty anyways ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have used option#2 as Ziv Weissman suggested.

1. Change the href value to another page.
2. Now in that page change the Session value to null
3. And redirect to certain page.